# How to show images based on true and false values which i am getting from model database in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to show images in a `table` based on true and false values based on 'user' collection. How can I do that?
Here is my code:

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="info-box">
    <div class="box-heading">
        <div class="box-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tabledetails">User Authorization</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 20px;" id="userauth">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 60px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">
                        <h6>Sl.NO</h6>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="1" style="border: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)">
                        <h6>Role</h6>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="1" style="border: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)">
                        <h6>Accept</h6>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="1" style="border: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)">
                        <h6>File</h6>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="1" style="border: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)">
                        <h6>Read</h6>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="1" style="border: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)">
                        <h6>Approve</h6>
                    </th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr dir-paginate="x in comptdata | itemsPerPage: 10" pagination-id="userpagination">
                    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Role}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.accept}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.file}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.read}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.approve}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now i am getting true and false only directly from collection but instead of true and false i want to show some images.

Answer (score 1):

You can add two img tags each for a value true or false:

```
<img ng-src="{{imgForTrue}}" ng-if="conditionIstrue">
<img ng-src-="{{imgForFalse}}" ng-if="!conditionIstrue">
```

Answer (score 0):

add an img tag with ng-if like

```
    <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-if="your condition" />
```